# Angular primeng carousel - custom display

Tags: angular, carousel, primeng

I have been assigned to display the carousel in a custom way. Not sure if that can be possible. Any help please...

https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-carousel-demo-vytqod

In the existing code the screen looks like below (one or two or three images based on screen size).
[image]

But the requirement is to display one image in the center and others (i.e. left and right) 30% like below
[image]

Comment: It's gonna be really painful. I highly recommand you to say no to this task since it involve editing code from an external library. You'll encouter bugs or weird behaviour and will waste your time on it. You could still try to find another libraby that does this natively

Comment: I am open for another library. Could you please suggest any library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have any package to give you sorry. But I produced something that looks like what you need.

Here is [the Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-carousel-demo-txedvg?file=src%2Fstyles.css) and here is the css code I added to get this view :

```
.p-carousel-container {
  width: 70% !important;
  margin: auto;
}

.p-carousel-items-content {
  overflow: visible !important;
  width: 70% !important; /* adapt this to show more/less of the sided items, but it should be the same % than for the p-carousel-container above */
}

.p-carousel-prev {
  z-index: 9999;
}

/* https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_hide_scrollbars.asp */

/* Hide scrollbar for Chrome, Safari and Opera */
.p-carousel-content::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

/* Hide scrollbar for IE, Edge and Firefox */
.p-carousel-content {
  -ms-overflow-style: none; /* IE and Edge */
  scrollbar-width: none; /* Firefox */
}
```

I hope it suits your needs. I didn't manage to limit these modifications for small screens only, i'll let you handle that. To test you can just shorten the stackblitz integrated browser.

Comment: Although I am looking a little different, but for now I will go with this and will keep working on this. Thanks  a lot, I upvoted

Comment: @SK. I edited the code so you can better see the sided items. I also centered ce container. I should be ok now :)

Comment: I have customized the Next and Previous button. can you please help me in removing the highlight color when click. I am posing this question in another thread. https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-carousel-demo-i1lnft